# Different \headheight in one document

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

I'm studying at a Cooperative State University and need to write a report about my activities at work. Our department provided us with templates for all kind of document we have to fill out and attach to our report and I converted them from Office to LaTeX documents. In the next step I wanted to combine all the templates to one single document.

Now my question is: Is there a way to define different `\headheight` in one document? I would need at least 4 different headers for all particular documents.

Here is an example of my documents code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
    \if@filesw % respect \nofiles
    \begingroup
        % same write register as environment `filecontents` uses
        \chardef\reserved@c=15 %
        \immediate\openout\reserved@c=\jobname.heights\relax
        \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
            \string\setlength{\string\headheight}{\the\headheight}%
        }%
        \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
            \string\setlength{\string\footskip}{\the\footskip}%
        }%
        \immediate\closeout\reserved@c
    \endgroup
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.heights}{}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 2.5cm, right = 2cm, includehead, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{./dhbw_logo}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{./cz_logo}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{plainpage}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

\begin{document}

    \input{./Deckblatt.tex}

    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plainpage}
    Hello World!

\end{document}
```

And here is an example of my title page:

```
\begin{titlepage}

    \thispagestyle{titlepage}

    \begin{center}

        ~\\[2.5cm]

        \textsc{\bfseries\LARGE\color{red} Praxisarbeitsthema} \\[2.5cm]

        \textsc{\Large Praxisarbeit} \\[1cm]
        \textsc{\Large für das 1. Studienjahr} \\[2cm]

        im Studiengang Informatik \\[0.5cm]
        an der Dualen Hochschule \\[0.5cm]
        Baden--Württemberg Heidenheim \\[1cm]

        vorgelegt von \\[0.5cm]
        \textsc{\Large Name} \\[2cm]

        \today

    \end{center}

    \vfill

    \begin{tabular}{ l l }
        Matrikelnummer: & whatever\\
        Ausbildungsfirma: & whatever\\
         & whatever | whatever \\
        Gutachter der Ausbildungsfirma: & {\color{red}Name}
    \end{tabular}

\end{titlepage}
```

As you can see, actually I hope you can, the header on the page after my title page still got the same `\headheight`, but without the content. I hoped that the `atveryend` package would set the `\headheight` for each page individually, but it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong.

So is there a nice and nifty way to solve this problem? And sorry for the really long question and code examples.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `geometry` package, you can set the `\headheight` using that. To set the initial value, use

```
\usepackage[...other options...,headheight=<length>]{geometry}
```

and to change it on successive pages, use

```
\newgeometry{headheight=<new value>}
```

However, all of the other options will also have to be given again in `\newgeometry`.

For more information, check the `geometry` package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf), also available from your local distrubution with `texdoc geometry`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply and it really does the job. I've got some little issues with the layout, but I think that shouldn't be a problem.