# Different headheights in one document (memoir)

Tags: spacing, header-footer, memoir

I am working on a document that should contain two different headers. The headers are generated by specifying `pagestyle`s. Unfortunately, the headers have vastly different heights, which makes the spacing around header content look bad.

How do I change the `headheight` for specific pages containing a different header? I have made a MWE to show the faulty version with only one `headheight`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Margin measures
\setulmarginsandblock{140pt}{\lowermargin}{*}   % {upper margin}{lower margin}{ratio}
\setheadfoot{5\baselineskip}{\footskip}         % {headheight}{footskip}
\setheaderspaces{72pt}{*}{*}                    % {headdrop}{headsep}{ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

% Header #1
\makepagestyle{pagestyle1}
\makeoddhead{pagestyle1}{}{Short header info}{}
\makeevenhead{pagestyle1}{}{Short header info}{}

% Header #2
\makepagestyle{pagestyle2}
\makeoddhead{pagestyle2}{}{Way\\way\\longer\\header\\info}{}
\makeevenhead{pagestyle2}{}{Way\\way\\longer\\header\\info}{}
\pagestyle{pagestyle2}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{pagestyle1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

To clarify: I would like something like `\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{\footskip}` for `pagestyle1`.

Note that I am using `memoir` which is why I am not following the answer given here: [Different \headheight in one document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118421/different-headheight-in-one-document)

EDIT:

As requested by daleif, I am trying to visualize a "real world example". See the image below. The image is part of the header while the tabulars below the header are different heights. Right now I only need the first page to contain "special information" as the rest of the pages would be identical to page 2. The above question is asked in order to generalize the problem/solution and thus obtain a less "hacky" document.

[image: Example image]

Comment: One obvious question is **why** do you need that much data in the header? Isn't there a better way to present this information to the reader?

Comment: @daleif: Maybe there is a better solution. I am open to suggestions. I need a lot of information presented on the top of the first page below the "typical" header information. On the remaining pages, I need a subset of said information on the top of the pages also immediately below the "typical" header. Because the first page contains a `longtable`, I am unable to include the subset-info before the "continued table" on the second page.

Did I mention that this is not a regular document? :-/

Comment: It would be nice to have a more closer to real life example. Suggestions really depend on the material. Changing the head height on and off all the time is not a good solution also not for the reader. I have used a lot of similar tricks, but where the additional information is not typeset as a part of the header.

Comment: You mean you want to move the textbody up on the pages with the short header? If (and how) this is possible depends a lot on how and where you switch between the headers. E.g. is there is clear place (e.g. with a \newpage)?. If you need the long header only on the first page, you could simply let it stick into the textbody and add a \vspace* before the longtable.

Comment: @daleif: See the edit. Is this close enough to "real life example"? Or am I way off?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the suggestion. That might work (I have not tested it yet). I was actually looking for a more general solution in case the layout changes to something else than only the first page being special.

Comment: As I wrote: It depends a lot of how you switch page styles. If you do a "\thispagestyle{}` in the middle of a page then LaTeX would have a hard time to adjust the textbody. It would probably be possible to insert something in the output box but as you are allowed to revert the page style in the next sentence you could easily confuse the output routine heavily.

Comment: I might not even use the header at all, but instead use the text block and a recursive `\afterpage` (using some algorithm that would terminate the recursion at some point (for example a certain macro having a certain value).

Comment: @Thomas: Will your documents only be two pages long typically? And/or, the *first* page has one head height, while pages 2+ have a different head height?

Comment: @Werner: My document is currently 4-5 pages long, but it is not limited in any way. And yes, the first page has one head height while the remaining pages have a different head height. (I was trying to generalize the question in order to be useful to other users. Maybe that just makes it difficult to answer.)

Comment: This is the standard letter style: first page with large info header (address, backaddress block etc) and small header page numbers on the following pages. This normally implemented with a vspace on the first page.

Comment: I sense this is a titlepage you want to do? If so, you shouldn't missuse headers on the title[age.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I want a `longtable` on the first page, so I'm not sure a titlepage is ideal. But I am obviously not the expert here. Feel free to give an example as I am not limited to header modification. That was just where my experimentation lead me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set the document page style to the default and adjust the first page to suit your needs.

The minimal example below moves the text on the first page up *into* the header, making it seem like the text block dimensions differ. You can fiddle around with some of the lengths to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Margin measures
\setulmarginsandblock{140pt}{\lowermargin}{*}   % {upper margin}{lower margin}{ratio}
\setheadfoot{5\baselineskip}{\footskip}         % {headheight}{footskip}
\setheaderspaces{72pt}{*}{*}                    % {headdrop}{headsep}{ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

% Header #1
\newcommand{\shortheadertext}{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Short header \\ info \end{tabular}}
\makepagestyle{pagestyle1}
\makeoddhead{pagestyle1}{}{\vphantom{\longheadertext}\shortheadertext}{}
\makeevenhead{pagestyle1}{}{\vphantom{\longheadertext}\shortheadertext}{}

% Header #2
\newcommand{\longheadertext}{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Way \\ way \\ longer \\ header \\ info \end{tabular}}
\makepagestyle{pagestyle2}
\makeoddhead{pagestyle2}{}{\longheadertext}{}
\makeevenhead{pagestyle2}{}{\longheadertext}{}
\pagestyle{pagestyle2}% Default page style

\AtBeginDocument{% First page is different
  \thispagestyle{pagestyle1}% Uses a smaller header...
  \vspace*{-4\baselineskip}% ...and moves the text up by 4 baselines
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

A similar technique can be used if the first header construct is taller/larger than subsequent headers; set the default page style to match the bulk of your document and adjust the first page with a positive `\vspace*` to push the text down far enough. You may have to remove the vertical space taken up by the larger header construction.

Comment: It would be possible to generalise the above in the following way: Store the header content for the two different headers in separate boxes. Measure the difference in height between the two boxes and use this to insert the appropriate `\vspace*` for the first page (either positive or negative).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a solution to the given question, but an alternative. This is using a recursive `\afterpage` to add information at the top of the page until we tell it to stop. There is a slight subtlety at the very end if there is no stop in the text, but this is just an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{afterpage,kantlipsum,etoolbox}

\newcommand\LongInfo{
  \begin{center}
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}

    \bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      Text & Text \\
      Text & Text \\
      Text & Text \\
      Text & Text 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}

\newcommand\ShortInfo{
  \begin{center}
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      Text & Text 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}

\newtoggle{FIRST}
\toggletrue{FIRST}

\newcommand\RunSmallInfo{
  \ifdef\STOP{}{
    \iftoggle{FIRST}{
      \global\togglefalse{FIRST}
    }{
      \ShortInfo
    }
    \afterpage{
      \RunSmallInfo
    }
  }
}

\AtEndDocument{\def\STOP}

\begin{document}

\LongInfo

\RunSmallInfo

\kant[1-15]


STOP
\def\STOP{}


\kant[1-15]



\end{document}
```

Comment: After looking at the [documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/float/afterpage.pdf) for the `afterpage` package, I'm a bit concerned with this solution -- although I like your idea. The documentation is from 1995 and it states that "This
implementation is _not_ particularly robust.". Since my document is to be generated automatically and not manually checked for layout errors, I'm not sure if this is a trustworthy solution. Am I just being paranoid?

Comment: @Thomas I have used this solution a few times. You just need to know exactly when it has to stop.